# How do I do to autoload composer classes only after the former autoload function failed to find a loadable class?

Tags: php, frameworks, composer-php

I'm taking over a project that uses a custom framework. Built-in, you find the most common PHP autoload function in the world:

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include APP_PATH . '/model/' . $class_name . '.php';
}
```

Now, I'd like to install composer. How do I do to autoload composer classes only after the former autoload function failed to find a loadable class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there is a way to register autoloader functions as a stack of functions that will be called until one succeeds. The last parameter [prepends](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) the autoloader function to the current stack.

```
spl_autoload_register('app_autoload', false, true);
```

But in order to be stacked it needed of course not to use the magic syntax (`__autoload()`) and also to be recognized as "not successful" the function must not include a file. So I changed the original function a little bit:

```
function app_autoload($class_name) {
    $file = APP_PATH . '/model/' . $class_name . '.php';
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        include $file;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And it worked as charm.